# docker-compose ignores DOCKER_HOST

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-on-windows

I am attempting to run 3 Docker images, MySQL, Redis and a project of mine on Bash for Windows (WSL).

To do that I have to connect to the Docker engine running on Windows, specifically on `tcp://locahost:2375`. I have appended the following line to `.bashrc`:

`export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375`

I can successfully run `docker` commands like `docker ps` or `docker run hello-world` but whenever I `cd` into my project directory and run
`sudo docker-compose up --build` to load the images and spin up the containers I get an error:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

I know that if I use the `-H` argument I can supply the address but I'd rather find a more permanent solution. For some reason `docker-compose` seems to ignore the `DOCKER_HOST` environmental variable and I can't figure out why..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is `sudo`. It's a totally different program than your shell and doesn't transfer the exported environment unless you specifically tell it to. You can either add the following line in your `/etc/sudoers` (or `/etc/sudoers.d/docker`):

```
Defaults env_keep += DOCKER_HOST
```

Or you can just pass it directly to the command line:

```
sudo DOCKER_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: you save my life!!

Answer (score 0):

By set `DOCKER_HOST` you tell for every run of docker in command line to use **http api**, instead of default - **socket** on localhost.

By default **http api** is not turned on

```
$ sudo cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service | grep ExecStart
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

you can add `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375` for tern on http api on localhost 
but usually you want to tern on api for remote servers by `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` **(do it only with proper firewall)**

so you need to change in  `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to next line

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```